# What interval (of x) does this power series converge for?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\right)x^n$$

I think we can write it in this form also:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right)x^n$

I tried the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}\right)x^{n+1}}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right)x^{n}}\right|$$

Here, I don't know what to do with those summations, because they're both infinity.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: ratio test.

Comment: I tried ratio test but, I becomes to an infinity divided by infinity. I don't know how to face it here.

Comment: Please show us, in full, that attempt, even if it fails. Edit your original post to include this.

Comment: These are some ideas that all solve this problem. (1) Note that the coefficients are partial sums. and the factors $x^n$ are easy to sum. Therefore, the series becomes "simpler" if you apply [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)

Comment: I don't know how to use summation by parts here. I've never used them. Can you explain more please?

Comment: [$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Growth_rate)$\sim\ln(n)$ can help you for the ratio test.

Comment: This is equivalent to the application of summation by part, and perhaps easier for you to see. Assume that $x$ is a value for which the series converges absolutely and call $S(x)$ the sum. Then compute $(1-x)S(x)=S(x)-xS(x)$. Note that $xS(x)$ is almost the same series but shifted. Cancel from $S(x)$ and $-xS(x)$ many many terms that have the same coefficient and the same power of $x$. You should get $(1-x)S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$.

Comment: [Harmonic series generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989255/harmonic-series-generating-function)

Comment: @user170231 That link was already present at the end of my answer before seeing your comment, but just as a complement for future readers, because the present question is more elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any integer $n\ge1,$
$$H_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\ge1$$ so, as $n\to+\infty,$
$$\frac{H_{n+1}}{H_n}=1+\frac1{(n+1)H_n}\to1$$
and
$$\frac{H_{n+1}|x|^{n+1}}{H_n|x|^n}\to|x|$$
hence the radius of convergence of this power series is equal to $1.$

Therefore, the series is absolutely convergent when $|x|<1,$ and trivially divergent (i.e. its general term does not tend to $0$) when $|x|>1.$

When $x=\pm1,$ it is also trivially divergent.

See [the sum of this power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989255).

Comment: I'm okay with everything, except of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \ln {n}$. Where does it come from? I searched wikipedia, but it wasn't so nice to me to understand.

Comment: The $\sim$ needs to be justfied. Please see my answer for some details.

Comment: Your answer was a motivation for mine. This ∼ is standard. I hinted it before in a comment and I repeated that link in my answer. The standard asymptotic estimate for the sequence of [harmonic numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number):$$H_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim\ln n$$is usually [proved by an integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Definition_and_divergence) but can also be viewed as a [consequence of the Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733438). But this rough estimate is even overkill. I edit now sth simpler

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in [1,\infty),$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\right)x^n\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ so the series diverges there.

So suppose $0\le x<1.$ Then, since $2+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+1}\le\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{t}dt,$ we have

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\right)x^n\le x^n-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+x^n\ln (n+1)$

so we conclude that the series converges (the last term converges, for example, by L'Hospital's rule.)

Now we are done, because the series has an interval of convergence symmetric about $x=0,$ so the foregoing implies that it converges in $(-1,1).$